# multiple LEFT JOIN - wrong output

Tags: mysql

I got this query:

```
SELECT r.name, date(r.join_date) as join_date,
(COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT n.id)) as num_likes,
COALESCE(SUM(rv.views), 0) as sum_views
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN apple_likes a ON r.id = a.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN android_likes n ON r.id = n.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN restaurant_views rv on r.id = rv.restaurant_id
WHERE r.id=192
GROUP BY r.id DESC
```

[image]

Here is another query with the **num_like** variable and LEFT JOIN's removed:

```
SELECT r.name, date(r.join_date) as join_date,
COALESCE(SUM(rv.views), 0) as sum_views
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN restaurant_views rv on r.id = rv.restaurant_id
WHERE r.id=192
GROUP BY r.id DESC
```

[image]

As you can see, the **sum_views changed to 1793** which is correct!
Meaning, when I removed the other LEFT JOIN's the sum_views display the correct value.
How can I make the upper query display the correct value on sum_views?
*(I can upload images of the structure of the other tables if requested!)*

---

**Edit:**
I found a way using sub-query to fix the problem

```
SELECT r.name, date(r.join_date) as join_date,
(COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT n.id)) as num_likes,
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(views), 0) FROM restaurant_views WHERE restaurant_id=192) as sum_views
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN apple_likes a ON r.id = a.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN android_likes n ON r.id = n.restaurant_id
WHERE r.id=192
GROUP BY r.id DESC
```

If someone knows how to solve this without using a sub-query I would be interested to hear it!

Comment: If you use the derived table/inline view `rv` from Gordon's query I suspect it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your `join`s are multiplying the number of rows.  One solution is to pre-aggregate the data before the joins:

```
SELECT r.name, date(r.join_date) as join_date,
       (coalesce(a.cnt, 0) + coalesce(n.cnt, 0)) as num_likes,
       COALESCE(SUM(rv.views), 0) as sum_views
FROM restaurants r LEFT JOIN
     (select a.restaurant_id, count(*) as cnt
      from apple_likes a
      group by a.restaurant_id
     ) a
     ON r.id = a.restaurant_id LEFT JOIN
     (select n.restuarant_id, count(*) as cnt
      from android_likes n
      group by n.restaurant_id
     ) n
     ON r.id = n.restaurant_id LEFT JOIN
     (select rv.restaurant_id, count(*) as cnt
      from restaurant_views rv
      group by rv.restaurant_id
     ) rv
     on r.id = rv.restaurant_id
WHERE r.id = 192
GROUP BY r.id DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! num_likes is always correct, so that doesn't need a change. It's only **sum_views** that is incorrect in the first query

Comment: @Tompa . . . It doesn't hurt to do all the calculations correctly.

Answer (score 0):

So try:

```
SELECT r.name, date(r.join_date) as join_date,
(COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT n.id)) as num_likes,
COALESCE(SUM(rv.views), 0) as sum_views
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN apple_likes a ON r.id = a.restaurant_id
LEFT JOIN android_likes n ON r.id = n.restaurant_id
INNER JOIN restaurant_views rv on r.id = rv.restaurant_id
WHERE r.id=192
GROUP BY r.id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT r.name, date(r.join_date) as join_date,
    (COUNT(DISTINCT a.id) + COUNT(DISTINCT n.id)) as num_likes,
    COALESCE(SUM(rv.views), 0) as sum_views
  FROM restaurants r
    JOIN apple_likes a ON r.id = a.restaurant_id
    JOIN android_likes n ON r.id = n.restaurant_id
    JOIN restaurant_views rv on r.id = rv.restaurant_id
  WHERE r.id=192
  GROUP BY r.id DESC;
```

Notice that I only remove the keyword `left` thus makes this a `natural join`, so that it will not include on counting all `null joins`.

Comment: Thanks for the input! Sadly the result stay the same with the LEFT's